Converting rectangles into squares on partially sculpted model?
I used subdivision surface to create additional geometry on a model so that I could sculpt some features onto it late into the modelling process.
Part way through sculpting I realized that I had inadvertently created a mesh made up of rectangles, rather than squares. Which is causing me problems with some sculpting tools.
It was my own fault, I didn't plan things out properly and made some changes without realizing the effect that they had had.
Is there an automated way that I can resize the rectangles into squares, even if this means distorting the model somewhat?
I have some backups but they are much earlier versions and going back to them means losing hours of sculpting.

you can try the Remesh/Quad tool: Data panel > Remesh > Quad. Or use a software like Instant Meshes
